# Variable value doesn't show during debug in Xcode with SFML library

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, sfml

I installed SFML to make some simple 2D game. It seems that the debugging in Xcode has some issue. I load the template code, and add a line

```
int a = 10;
```

Set the breakpoint at this line. But in the debug window, **a** has no value.

[image: code with SFML]

The code without SFML looks ok.
[image: code without SFML]

Is it related to LLDB?

- Mac OS X 10.10
- Xcode 6.1.1
- SFML 2.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is linked to the build settings of your project. When creating a SFML project, some debug settings are not ideal apparently.

There are three settings that need to be updated for the Debug settings (not Release):

- *Debug Information Format* should be *DWARF with dSYM File*,
- *Strip Debug Symbols During Copy* should be *No*, and
- *Optimization Level* should be *None*.

You have to manually correct them as shown in this screenshot:

[image: build settings]